# Logical iteration over numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, vectorization

Suppose that you have two equal-sized lists. First list contains only zeros and ones, and initial value of second list is equal to some fixed number. Other values of second array depends on same-indexed values of first list. Relation between them is that, if value in first list is equal to 0, same-indexed value of second list is equal to preceding one, in all other cases, is equal to some other value. In order to clarify my question, I've written the code below with help of for loop. What is the way to solve this like problem without for loop?

```
Code
a = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[0] = 5
for i in range(1, a.size):
    if a[i] == 0:
        b[i] = b[i-1]
    else:
        b[i] = np.random.randint(5)
```

Comment: Since your construction explicitly depends on previous iterations, it's not straightforward at all that it can be vectorized. Not necessarily *impossible*, but difficult.

Comment: If your `a` array doesn't contain adjacent ones, it can be done easily. Is that the case, by any chance?

Comment: I know, it's difficult. But, I'm trying to find that, whether there is straight forward solution like "scipy.signal.lfiler" function. With that function, I can do numerical previous value depended iteration.

Comment: No, Andras, there will be adjacent same values.

Comment: For the code2 : `c = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=int)` maybe?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Or np.zeros_like(b).

Comment: It seems answering for code#2 would involve wholesome changes going from the solution for code #1. I would suggest posting a new question for code#2.

Comment: Will you write solution in new question?

Comment: @ElginCahangirov  Can't promise, would give it a shot! :)

Comment: Ok. I'm posting new question. :)

Comment: You might want to edit out code#2  while moving to the new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
offset = int(a[0]!=0)
N = (np.count_nonzero(a!=0)) - offset # no. of rand num to be generated
rand_num = np.append(5,np.random.randint(0,5,N))
out = rand_num[(a!=0).cumsum() - offset]
```

Comment: Doesn't this keep the same values between ones, instead of generating new randoms inside? Running with `a=np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])` I'd expect the second value to be 5 too; unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well in that second position case, since `a[i] != 0:` should go into ELSE part and generate a new number in `[0,5]`. So, we would have a random number at second position, right?

Comment: Good solution! But, what if there would be strings instead of zeros and ones(for example 'a's and 'b's)?

Comment: Bah, I misread the meaning of `a` (swapped 1 and 0 in my head)! Sorry, you're right, it's fine:)

Comment: @ElginCahangirov Well it would change a lot of things - 1) How would you compare against `0`? 2) What would happen to random number generation? Consider adding a new sample case to demo the expected behavior.

Comment: I've modified my post and added second code, which exactly shows my problem. Thank you for your interest!